# Change a variable in a URL (within HTML) on a Javascript event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript event that is fired when a location is detected. Let's say that the detected location is "Melbourne Australia".

I want to change the following:

```
<a href="/search?location=&input=Suits">Suits</a>
```

To be:

```
<a href="/search?location=Melbourne Australia&input=Suits">Suits</a>
```

All I can think of us changing the entire `href` value. Is there a 'sane' way to change only the value of `location=` when the event is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a id to your link

```
<a href="/search?location=&input=Suits" id="my_link">Suits</a>
```

and use js to modify it

```
var your_location = "Melbourne Australia"; // can be dynamic

var obj = document.getElementById('my_link');

var h = obj.href;

var string_to_find = "location=";
var string_to_replace = "location="+your_location;
var new_h = h.replace(string_to_find, string_to_replace);

obj.href=new_h;
```